# Rails Geocoding using address city and state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding

I'm using the rails geocoder gem and have the following in my location model

```
geocoded_by :address
```

but my location has other attributes such as city, state, and country which affect the outputted address.

How do I make the geocoding occur through all 4 inputs? I have tried creating a full_address variable with all four attributes but I don't know where that actually goes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rather than a variable, you can use a method that will collate those attributes into a single string, e.g.:

```
def full_street_address
  [address, city, state, country].compact.join(', ')
end
```

Then you can just change your geocoded_by line to:

```
geocoded_by :full_street_address
```

Comment: Where am I putting this? Just to be sure.